# How does this basic Python code based on booleans work?

Tags: python, boolean

```
x = False

if x:
     print 'x was True!'
else:
     print 'I will be printed in any case where x is not true'
```

In the first line of the code, we assign the value of x = False.

I want to understand what does the line 'if x:' means. 
When x has a value of False, doesn't it imply that the line 'if x:' would be executed as 'if False:'. And hence, the statement 'x was True!' should be printed.

But instead,'I will be printed in any case where x is not true' is printed.

I think I am having some problems understanding how Booleans work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if

Comment: An if clause is executed if it's value is true. So if x is False "print 'x was True!'" "won't be executed and the else clause will instead.

Comment: I guess I confused the boolean operator with a conditional statement. Thanks.

Comment: You are confusing `x` with `x == False`.

Answer (score 2):

Python does't understand English. It has **no idea** what the stuff in quotes after `print` actually *means*. So if execution gets to the line `print 'x was True!'` it just blindly prints out that text. But execution *won't* get to that line.

In

```
if some_expression:
    do_this_stuff()
else:
    do_that_stuff()
```

First, `some_expression` is evaluated.
If it has a Boolean value of `True` then `do_this_stuff()` will be called.
But if `some_expression`has a Boolean value of `False`, then `do_that_stuff()` will be called.

Your code has,`if x:`, where `x` is `False`, so only the code in the `else` part gets executed.

---

The expression following `if` can be *any* expression, it doesn't have to be an actual Boolean `True` or `False`.

In Python, "null" objects of various kinds are considered to be False when they appear in a Boolean context: this includes the number zero, the empty string `''`, the empty list `[]`, the empty tuple `()`, the empty dictionary `{}`, and the empty set `set()`; I think you can see the pattern. :) Non-null objects are considered to be True.

This is a handy feature that makes code more succinct, and more readable, once you are used to it.

Answer (score 0):

else block will execute only if the if condition is false. 
So in this code on giving False here it will jumps to else block.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of an if...else statement is :

```
if boolean_expression :
    # statement(s) will execute if the boolean expression is true
else
    # statement(s) will execute if the boolean expression is false
```

If the Boolean expression evaluates to True, then the if block will be executed, otherwise, the else block will be executed.